# Is it possible to implement stack with only pointer to structure (no data type)?

Tags: c, pointers, stack

Suppose I have the following structure

```
typedef struct _Stack {
   struct _Stack *next;
} Stack;
```

Note in above there is no data type for storage, only `*next` pointer to structure. So, my question is will it be possible that the following function is valid.

```
void stackPush(Stack **stackP, void *dataP) {
    Stack *data = (Stack*)dataP;

    data->next = *stackP;
    *stackP = data;
}
```

I saw this function in `glib` library in the file `gtrashstack.c`. But when I compiled above, I got a warning : `In data->next : assignment from incompatible pointer type`.

I know that, I can rewrite the structure with generic pointer. But I only want to know, why the above will not work?

**Update**: My mistake, here I write `typedef struct _Stack` but in my program, I missed `_Stack`.

Comment: Your question is based on a false premise. It's valid and it will work. Though `data->next = *stackP` should probably be written `data->next = &(stackP->next);` or `data->next = (struct _Stack *) *stackP;`.

Comment: why not `data->next = (Stack *)*stackP`

Comment: Because `data->next` is of type `struct _Stack *`, not `Stack *`.

Comment: @David data->next = (Stack*)*stackP` also work. It's my mistake, I forget to add `_Stack` in `typedef struct`  in my original program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function is valid. Probably it is used for different structures like:

```
 typedef struct my_Stack {
   struct my_Stack *next;
   sometype1 somename1;
   ...
   sometypen somenamen;
 } MyStack;
```

i.e. for the lists where the pointer to the next elem is placed as the first field of the structure. It is the same trick as when classes are built via simple inheritance in C++. For such a structure you can call:

```
x = malloc(sizeof(struct my_Stack));
x->somename1 = aaa; ...
stackPush(&mylist, x);
```

I am not sure if this style of programming is supported by the C standard. It's not a good style for novices. It is for developers who know what they are doing in C.

Comment: So it means, we can also implement `linked list` with only pointer to structure and no data type.

Comment: It is the same thing.

Comment: it's better said that it's just a trick. the data **IS** there right next to the next pointer. But in the **context** of `stackPush` it **didn't need to care** how big the data was. so it just received `*dataP` as **void pointer**; interpret it as having a 'next' pointer at that address (not caring that there might also be data in the following address); then just do `stackPush`

Comment: So it's just a way to implement `stackPush` for any type of linked-list node, independent of what the data type is. as long as the linked-list node declare next pointer as the first variable in the struct.

Comment: @ashish2expert Check keyword: Intrusive list, there is an implemention in kernel.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes, it is possible to implement stack with only pointer to structure (no data type). See implementation of generic list or queue in c in Linux (don't know if it is implemented in windows also).  See how it is implemented [Linux Kernel Linked List Explained](http://isis.poly.edu/kulesh/stuff/src/klist/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I really want this

Comment: @ashish2expert Pay attention to the list_entry macro which returns pointer to the actual data struct given absolute memory address of inner filed list( this will be stack in your case)